# Switching user inside tmux session: Cannot attach to other tmux server

Tags: ssh, permissions, users, tmux

I have this scenario on a server

1. `userA` (uid 1000) logs in over SSH and starts a tmux server and some sessions
2. `userB` (uid 1001) logs in over SSH and runs `su userA` to become `userA` *inside of a tmux session*
3. `userB` (as `userA`) now runs `tmux ls` or any other tmux command.
4. The result is `error connecting to /tmp/tmux-1001/default (Permission denied)`

It's strange that the error hints at `/tmp/tmux-1001/` which seems to be a tmux server for user id `1001` which is `userB`), whereas `userA` has uid 1000. So it seems that the tmux command run inside tmux attempts to connect to the wrong server.

When `userB` does their thing outside of tmux, there is no problem.

What is the reason for this?

Answer (score 2):

tmux works out the socket by looking at the `TMUX` environment variable if it exists. You need to unset it when you switch user or use `-S` to point it to the socket directly.